# How to mock d3.select.selectall with sinon?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sinon

I have the following code that I need to test:

```
window.d3.select(id).selectAll("text").attr("font-family", "FontAwesome"); 

var textsSelected = window.d3.select(id).selectAll('text');

var filtered = textsSelected.filter(function(value, index, arr) {
    return !((value===undefined)||(typeof (value) === "number"));
});
```

I am struggling to be able to mock it so both lines are run without it crashing with an error.

Currently I have

```
var texts = {
    _group:[
        [{id: "textID2#StatusChangeChart",
           textContent: " New", 
           __data__: "hi"
            }]
        ],
    fontFamily: "shouldChange",
    __proto__:{
        attr: function (name, value) {
            if (name === 'font-family') {
                // this works
                this.fontFamily = value;
            }
        }
    }

};


var d3Select = sinon.stub(window.d3,'select');

 d3Select.withArgs("#testUpdateImage").returns({
    selectAll: function (e) {

        var objectToReturn = imageUpdateGroups;

        switch (e) {
           //stuff here
            case "text":
                objectToReturn = texts;

                //TODO
                break;

           //stuff here

        }
        return objectToReturn;
    }
});
```

as the mock.

I get the error `TypeError: array.filter is not a function` and my console.log statements show the attr does change as it should.

*What is textsSelected supposed to be?*

Typing `window.d3.select('#PhaseChangeChart').selectAll('text');` into the console returns (groups has been expanded for visual purposes):

```
Ct {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}
  _groups: Array(1)
       0: NodeList(48) [text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, 
                    text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, 
                    text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, 
                    text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, 
                    text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, 
                     text, text, text, text]
       length: 1
       __proto__: Array(0)
   _parents: [svg#PhaseChangeChart]
   __proto__: Object
```

where each `text` is a text element.

Comment: Check whether **array** is js array

Comment: @Rishab turns out that name is super misleading. Running the actual code (not my tests): typeof(array) returns Object. Array.isArray(array) returns false. So it isn't even supposed to be an array that I'm mocking. Confusing that filter works but it does when I'm not testing.

Comment: update: changes the variable name

Comment: update: described what textsSelected is supposed to be

Comment: I added a temporary answer but if there are any better ones please let me know. I'd rather not mock filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Temporary answer until someone has a better one (one that doesn't involve mocking `filter`)**

Adding a filter function to `__proto__` stops the error.

```
var toFilter =[
    {
        0: [
            {
                id: "textID2#StatusChangeChart",
                textContent: "New",
                __data__: "hi"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var texts = {
    _group: toFilter,
    fontFamily: "shouldChange",
    __proto__:{
        attr: function (name, value) {
            if (name === 'font-family') {
                this.fontFamily = value;
            }
        },
        filter: function (value, index,arr){
            return {_groups:[undefined]};
        }
    }

};
```

Personally, I'll need to change `undefined` to actually return things I can change the`style` of for the rest of the function I'm testing so the actual functionality of the function this is in can be tested. But for anyone wondering how to solve the issue in the future just add your own function instead of using the pre-made library functions. You are not testing their functionality. You are testing yours. Make it return what you want it to return and see if your function holds up with the data you expect it to hold up with.

Comment: Of course, mocking filter feels like one of the worst thing I have ever done in the name of a test since I do care that filter returns the correct things when I'm not testing it but I can only assume it does due the function working properly when I'm not testing.